# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: close the app, not the tabs

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, popups

After I click the usual "close app" icon (`X`) there is a (unexpected) pop-up window:

[image]

Why this window? How to close Adobe Acrobat Reader DC w/o any pop-up windows? Actually I don't want to close *tabs*, I want to close the app. (So, then next time the app is opened, the previously opened tabs are still opened.) Any help?

---

UPD. Workaround: `File => Exit Application`.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog box would suggest you have one window open, with more than one tab. Browsers ask this too under similar circumstances.

If you want the entire app to always close, just check the 'always close all tabs' box & hit the 'Close all tabs' button.

Comment: Does it mean that when the app will be opened again, the tabs will be opened too?

Comment: Presumably that would be a separate pref. It would take 30s to test it.